# RadGrid PageSizeComboBox is not finding

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid

The PageSizeComboBox of radgrid giving me null result either in ItemDataBound Event or any other event. I need to get the selected value of RadGrid PageSizeComboBox. What should I do to get PageSizeComboBox

here is my code written in ItemDataBound event of Grid

```
 if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
     {
                RadComboBox PageSizeCombo = e.Item.FindControl("PageSizeComboBox") as RadComboBox;
     }
```

I need to get this control. I want to get it on my Button Click event also.
Can any one help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
if (e.Item is GridPagerItem)  
    {     
        GridPagerItem pagerItem = (GridPagerItem)e.Item;  
        RadComboBox PageSizeCombo = (RadComboBox)pagerItem.FindControl("PageSizeComboBox");  
        // Access ComboBox here   
    }
```

For more information please check below link.
http://jayeshgoyani.blogspot.in/2012/06/customizing-items-of-radgrid-page-size.html